# Word for "many" for mass nouns

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, uncountable-nouns, modifiers

I'm looking for a strong size modifier like "numerous", "countless", or "copious" that I can use to modify a mass noun. I know of plenty of options that involve several words, like "a lot of", "a huge amount of", "large quantities of", and so on, but I can't think of any that are only a word or two.

#### Mass Nouns

Mass nouns, also known as uncountable nouns, are words like "rice", "water", and "bread" that can't be described with a quantity like other (countable) nouns. *I ate 4 rices* or *I drank several waters* don't really make sense, you have to use special modifiers like "some" and "much" (*I baked so much bread the other day*), but there are a lot fewer of these special modifiers.

#### The Ultimate Question

Does anyone know of *one or two words* that can fit in the following sentences to indicate A LOT:

*I've baked ______ bread throughout my 27 years in the baker.*

*Wikipedia has ______ information about a myriad of topics.*

Comment: Considerable, copious, profuse, ample.

Comment: 'Tons of', 'shedloads of', 'oodles of', 'mountains of', 'bags of', 'piles of', 'stacks of', 'bundles of' ....

Comment: The usual mass opposite of _many_ is _much_: _Not many people/Not much attendance at the service today_. But they're  only parallel in a negative context; _much_ isn't used much in the affirmative: _I've baked much bread_ is grammatical but odd. Normally another quantifier would be used, like _a lot, quite a bit, some,_ etc.

Comment: If you are just looking for what is typical in conversation, "tons of" > "lots of".  You can also add additional "lots" or "tons", i.e. "lots and lots and LOTS of bread!" though it can sound childish depending on usage.

Answer (score 1):

> I've baked ***[masses of](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/masses_of.html#C0-1)*** bread throughout my 27 years in the bakery.

> Wikipedia has [***profuse***](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/profuse.html#C0-3) or ***abundant*** information about a myriad of topics.

(do check the links for ***a wealth of*** synonyms :)

Answer (score 0):

The formal alternative of 'many' which can be used for mass nouns is

> [much](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/much),

as in

> I see **many** dogs.

but

> I see **much** water.

The more common and slightly informal versions works for both count and mass nouns

> a lot of,

as in

> I see **a lot of** dogs.

> I see **a lot of** water.

There are many synonyms of these, but these are the most common.

Answer (score 0):

A few other suggestions:

> *considerable* ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/considerable))
>
> Wikipedia has *considerable* information about a myriad of topics.

> *abundant* ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/abundant))
>
> Wikipedia has *abundant* information about a myriad of topics.

> *tons* ([Webersts](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ton))
>
> I've baked *tons* of bread throughout my 27 years in the baker.

> *extensive* ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extensive))
>
> Wikipedia has *extensive* information about a myriad of topics.

> *exorbitant* ([Websters](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exorbitant))
>
> I've baked *exorbitant* amounts of bread throughout my 27 years in the baker.